# Specific table layout

Tags: html, css, adaptive-design, adaptive-layout

I want to make an adaptive table with vertical left header row on mobile like this:

```
Header 1  data data data
Header 2  data data data
Header 3  data data data
```

And normal table for desktop like this:

```
Header 1 Header 2 Header 3
 data     data      data
 data     data      data
```

Has anybody ideas how can I do this only with CSS and HTML (I want to make table so it can be easy to add new rows by PHP).

Comment: Hi, use ul li structure for it.

Comment: Can you show an example, please?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mediaqueries and reset display values to the table elements:

```css
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  border-collapse:collapse;/* whatever */
}
th, td {
  width:100px;/* whatever */
  border:solid;/* See me */
}
th {
  color:#145492
}
@media all and (max-width : 640px) {
  table {
    width:100%;/* whatever needed */
  }
  tbody {
    display:table-row;/* optionnal*/
  }
  tr {
    display:table-cell;    
  }
  th, td {
    display:block;
    width:auto;/* reset width if needed */
  }
}
tr:last-of-type {
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:1px 1px tomato;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header</th>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>header</th>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>header</th>
    <td>test snippet</td>
    <td>in full</td>
    <td>page mode</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## edit, just noticed layout is the other way round. maybe you can produce your HTML, so i can update the snippet, anyhow, the method is there whatever the structure will be like ;)

## thank you

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply put the `<th>` tags where you need them.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Header 1</th>
  <td>Content 1,1</td>
  <td>Content 1,2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Header 2</th>
  <td>Content 2,1</td>
  <td>Content 2,2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Header 3</th>
  <td>Content 3,1</td>
  <td>Content 3,2</td>
</tr></table>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/daswagpanda/byxk0rt6/

Comment: The shows the mobile layout on both mobile and desktop

Comment: No, that's works good only for mobile. I want exactly the structure as I mentioned. (Designer wants me to make like that and I have no idea how to do it =[ )

Comment: @Simon Oh yes. May I ask why you can't use JavaScript? It would be really easy with JS.

Answer (score -1):

Your Layout Requirement needs Javascript code ,
or 
detect in PHP if the request is from Mobile or Desktop and then render the required layout in PHP